# "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError for a given algorithm analysis

Tags: java, exception, stack-overflow

I know this has been asked a lot, but i couldn't figure out my problem.

I'm trying to get the time-complexity, but I get this error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at MedianAlgorithm2.Select(MedianAlgorithm2.java:22)

when I pass an array size > 100000.

and the recursive select method as follows:

```
public static int Select(int[] A, int l, int m, long h) {   
    int pos = Partition(A, l, h);
    if (pos == m) {
        return A[pos];
    }
    if (pos > m) {
        return Select(A, l, m, pos - 1);
    }
    if (pos < m) {
        return Select(A, pos + 1, m, h); // this is line 22 mentiond in exception
    }
    return 0;
}

public static int Partition(int[] A, int l, long h) {
    int pivotval = A[l];
    int pivotloc = l;   
    for (int j = l+1; j <= h; j++) {
        if (A[j] < pivotval) {
            pivotloc = pivotloc + 1;
            int temp = A[pivotloc];
            A[pivotloc] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    int temp = A[l];
    A[l] = A[pivotloc];
    A[pivotloc] = temp;
    return pivotloc;
}
```

I've changed h from int to long, but I'm still getting an error

Thank you.

Comment: What happens if in the initial call to `Select` both `l` and `h` are less than `m` or both are more than `m`? Does `Partition(...)` handle this well? On a side note, you should take some time looking into java naming standards and recommendations for methods and variables.

Comment: You'll need to post the `Partition` code as well.

Answer (score -3):

Your JVM is running out of memory. You need to simply assign it more.

Comment: `StackOverflowError`? Because of running out of memory? Please explain your reasoning.